# How to animate an element on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

How can I make my `<div>` elements grow (and the content changes text size to a higher one), when hovered over? I put them in a class and tried:

```
size: 150%;
```

and

```
height: +30px;
width: +30px;
```

the first try didn't work at all, and the second code just made the div's flash and dissappear partially.

Comment: It can only be done using in CSS using CSS3 that is not supported in older browsers such as everything before IE9, FF4 Safari 4 and Chrome 15. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @laymanje well i'm only triing to increase the size of one div, while hovered, it doesn't matter if or if not this div overlaps another on 
my site:
http://maxwf.net16.net/index/index.html
(that you know what i mean by div)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS3 solution:

```css
div {
    background: #999;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px; 
    transition: width 1s;
}

div:hover{
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Im content</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MrdvW/

Answer (score 5):

I did something like this for a similar problem (you can change the scale to whatever works for you):

```css
div:hover {
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 -moz-transform:    scale(1.1);
 -o-transform:      scale(1.1);
 -ms-transform:     scale(1.1);
}
```

Note that this will scale both the div and its content, which I think is what you want.

Comment: thk very much.
yes it is what i was looking for xD,
but ive used the answer below to do it and it looks pretty good already!

Answer (score 4):

Using CSS you can add a hover style to the div:

```
div.container {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
}

div.container:hover {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7bTW/1/) for a demonstration.

**jQuery Solution**

Another option that might work for you is [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery). It's a JavaScript library that simplifies commonly needed functionality such as this. Using jQuery, you can easily add hover effects to the elements:

```
//hover effect applies to any elements using the 'container' class
$(".container").hover(
    function(){ //mouse over
        $(this).width($(this).width() + 30);
    },
    function(){ //mouse out
        $(this).width($(this).width() - 30);
    }
);
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ryq44/1/) for a demonstration.

Comment: thx, but there's one prob. with that, i can't define the size in %,because i have 3+ divs next to each other, like this:http://jsfiddle.net/epS96/ (js fiddle doesn't show the css properly) and i want each div to be able to grow....

Comment: @Fr0stY, you can use any unit for setting the widths, try fiddling with his example.

Comment: ok thx.
is there something to tell it to be the existing width plus 30 px or so
like width: width+30px;
     height: height+30px;

Comment: Just hard code it :) if you're only changing between two sizes, a normal size and a hover size, I'd recommend using specific numbers to keep from accidentally getting strange results

Comment: ok. i guess thats the only thing to do :( but :) thx for all help :D:D

Comment: The other alternative is to use something like jQuery to handle the resizing, or possibly a combination of both. With jQuery you would be able to expand the elements by a fixed number of pixels.

Comment: what is jquery and how do you use it is it like a script or css?

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library that simplifies commonly needed functionality like what you need. I'll edit my answer and post an example.

Comment: @Fr0stY: I updated my answer with a jQuery example and Fiddle. There's also a link to the download the latest version.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me... seems to achieve the effect you were looking for.

Comment: of course the colors etc are just for displaying purposes, and i'm not trying to copy the Metro design, but just the "fields"