# How can I animate the height of the bottom border seen in this website?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate this effect shown in [complex.com](http://complex.com) where there is a colored bottom-border on the three large panels at the top of the site. When you hover over the panel the height of the bottom border gets slightly larger in an animated effect. Here is the code I believe makes the effect, still confuse on what :after does. I only want to animate the border of the panel or div, not the entire panel/div.

```
.hero-unit--style:after {
   background: #d93347;
 }

 .hero-unit:after {
   display: block;
   height: 3px;
   background: #000;
   transition: height .2s,box-shaddow .2s;
  }
 .hero-unit:after, .hero-unit__img-shadow {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
  }
```

Comment: You can check out the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3A%3Aafter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to animate an element on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017893/how-to-animate-an-element-on-hover)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pseudo-element. It only exists as a styling effect for the element it's attached to. Then it's properties are changed/transitioned on hover of it's owning element. In other words, it's not a border at all.

[**Per MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3A%3Aafter)

> The CSS ::after pseudo-element matches a virtual last child of the selected element. It is typically used to add cosmetic content to an element by using the content CSS property. This element is inline by default.

Basically, it works like this:

```css
body {
  background: #c0ffee;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background: white;
  margin: 2em auto;
  position: relative;
  /* positioning context */
}
div::after {
  content: '';
  /* required */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* positioned at the bottom */
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  /* no height to start */
  background: darkorange;
  transition: height .5s ease;
}
div:hover::after {
  height: 16px;
  /*finishing height */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only few things that should interest you

```
hero-unit--pop-culture:after
hero-unit--style:after
hero-unit--music:after
```

These are just for the color of the "border" **(it's not a border, it's pseudo element :after)**

And then:

```
.no-touch .hero-unit:hover:after
```

is for the height of the "border" on hover

```
.hero-unit:after {
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    background: #000;
    transition: height 0.2s,box-shaddow 0.2s;
}
```

The `height` in this is the starting height and the `transition: height 0.2s` is for the animation. It means that it will change the height attribute from the default one (3px) to the value which is set in the `.no-touch .hero-unit:hover:after` part. The `0.2s` is the transition time of the animation.

After that there are just the basic **:after** stuff like `content: ''` which is mandatory.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great and they beat me to it! But I'll leave this anyway just in case my weird way of explaining things is at all helpful! :D

---

So.. there are these things called "Pseudo-Classes" and also "Pseudo-Elements".

Examples of pseudo-elements:

- ::before
- ::after
- ::selection

Examples of pseudo-classes:

- :active
- :hover
- :focus

As the other answers have pointed out, the one you might want to use is `:hover`.

It works like this:

```
.myClass {
    //Default styling (for when it's not being hovered)       
}

.myClass:hover {
    //Styling for when the element is hovered over.
}
```

You can also add the `transition` property to add a time-delay and/or animation effect when the element is hovered.

**e.g.**

```
transiton: .3s ease;
```

---

To answer your question regarding the `:after` pseudo-element, what this basically does is inject an extra little snippet of content *AFTER* all the other content nested inside the selected element, and just before the closing tag.

**e.g.**

**CSS:**

```
.myClass::after {
   content: "I AM AN AFTER PSEUDO ELEMENT";
}
```

**Raw HTML:**

```
<div class="myClass">
     <h1>WHATEVER</h1>
     <p>blah blah blah</p>
     <p>More rubbish content</p>         
</div>
```

**HTML interpreted by browser after applying CSS:**

```
<div class="myClass">
     <h1>WHATEVER</h1>
     <p>blah blah blah</p>
     <p>More rubbish content</p>   
     :after
</div>
```

**What you will actually see on the page:**

---

## WHATEVER

blah blah blah

More rubbish content

I AM AN AFTER PSEUDO ELEMENT

---

I hope that clears things up for you a bit and helps you with your problem! :)

Comment: Aha ok my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out. I will correct my answer :)